# "cannot find symbol" while trying to compile a java file that implements an interface

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile a class `Tmp` that implements an interface `TmpInter`.

```
/* Interface */
package test;

public interface TmpInter {
  public void show(String s);
}

/* Class */
package test;

public class Tmp extends TmpInter {
  public void show(String s) {
    System.out.println("hello");
  }
}
```

Now when I'm trying to compile the class `Tmp.java` I'm getting the error

```
D:\java\rmi\Hello>javac TmpInter.jav

D:\java\rmi\Hello>javac Tmp.java
Tmp.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol: class TmpInter
public class Tmp extends TmpInter
                         ^
```

I went through all the similar posts and tried those solutions but, in vain.

I'm saving and running both the files in the same directory and the `.class` files are being generated in the same folder. I tried the `-classpath` option as well but didn't work. I'm compiling these files from the windows cmd when tried in Eclipse it is working fine. Also I tried compiling all the files at a time in that folder using `javac *.java` this is generating all the required `.class` files without any error but iam unable to figure out why this is not so when compiled individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides what Binyamin said, make sure that the current directory is in the classpath. Try compiling like this:

```
javac -cp . test\Tmp.java
```

(Run this from the directory that contains the `test` package directory).

The `-cp` option sets the classpath. `.` means "the current directory". Normally, if you do not have the `CLASSPATH` environment variable set, the current directory is automatically in the classpath. But if you've set `CLASSPATH` and didn't add the current directory explicitly, it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but iam still not able to compile it.

Comment: Your source files have a `package test;` statement. That means you must put them in a subdirectory named `test`. Save your source files in `D:\java\rmi\Hello\test` and then from `D:\java\rmi\Hello` compile with the command above.

Answer (score 3):

TmpInter  is interface. You can't extend interface to a class. Interfaces can implement to a class.

```
public class Tmp implements TmpInter
```

[Declaring Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html)

Create sub folder(test) in Hello folder. After that put those interface and class into test sub folder. Then, you compile your code.

```
D:\java\rmi\Hello\test>javac Tmp.java
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but iam still unable to resolve this problem.Even if iam using the implements keyword instead of extends the same error is being thrown "cannot find symbol".

Answer (score 2):

You should **implement** interface, not extend it.

```
public class Tmp implements TmpInter
```

Also, look at the [Java tutorials of inteface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Comment: Iam sry abt that i tried implementing the ineterface by replacingthe extends with implements keyword but iam still facing the same problem. As the error described here indicates that it is a "cannot find symbol" and also if i remove the package statement at the 1st line it is compiling but i dont understand why it is not compiling with that statement present.

Answer (score 0):

i tried doing `javac -d . filename.java` in the same path `D:\java\rmi\Hello` this produced the required output that is .class for each file were generated individually in the package mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

for interface do this

```
D:\java\rmi\Hello>javac test\TmpInter.java
```

then try

```
D:\java\rmi\Hello>javac test\Tmp.java
```

it work's

all the best